# iphone development and jailbreak

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone development.
We can develop iphone applications through:

1. legal
2. jail breaking

If I jail break my iphone OS, after that can I install latest version of iphone OS
and make it as legal again from apple site?

If I develop jail break applications, can I install it in iphone without apple
authorization like provisioning, certificates etc.?

Why apple did not protect against these operations (jail breaking)?

How do the companies which provide jail breaking software know the apple iphone os  structure?

Why did apple develop iphone OS without protection, security?
For example if I use BREW, it is protected by qualcomm.

Comment: You can always restore your iPhone, and it will be as if it was never jailbroken, however it is fraud to pretend it never was, like using your warranty even though you know you jailbroke you iPhone. Not that jailbreaking in itself is illegal, it just voids your warranty. And yes, you can install iphone applicatons (and distribute them) for jailbroken iPhones without paying for the 99$/year program, or needing provisioning and certificates (its not a workaround to not pay $99, the $99 is for distributing on the app store).

Answer (score 2):

If you develop apps for the jail breaking community you are severely limiting the amount of money that can be made with an app.  It's dishonest because when you sign up as an Apple developer, you agree explicitly NOT to do such a thing.

No device can be fully protected from tampering.  However, Apple is concerned about security, this is why they control the AppStore, so you don't give hackers access to your phone.  When you jail break your phone, you are opening the door for all kinds of maliciousness.

If you want security and safety, stick with what Apple has given you.  Don't add to the sillyness of jail breaking.  It has also been rumored that in future OS updates, Apple will 'brick' phones that have been tampered with, rendering the phones useless as they won't be compatible with future updates.

I think legal and honorable software development is the only kind that should be advocated on stack overflow.

Comment: Except you don't need to be a paying developer to create and distribute applications for jailbroken iPhones. And jailbroken iphone software development is not illegal or dishonest. Its for people who want the full potential of their product. Don't mix up jailbreaking with pirating applications. And its impossible to brick an iPod Touch atleast, without ripping out wires. What about on a desktop computer? No third party software at all? No changing the wallpaper? No looking at the filesystem? Jailbroken iPhones are suited for developers, who know what they're doing.

Comment: @Mk12 Your opinion is just a child's dream. And even you're right, And not matching to fact.

First, jail-breaken device cannot be used for development. Because it has unknown code which modifies platform behavior. If you make production code, first goal is stability, so with the device, you cannot prove behavior of your app.

Comment: Second, I can't judge jail-breaking is legal or illegal, however, it's obvious unfair because it's SDK contract violation.(not your law)

Of course, you can do anything with yours, but you cannot use SDK without agreeing with the terms because SDK is Apple's. If you want your rights, you have to respect other's rights.

So if you're using Xcode with jail-breaken device, you're just stealing other's work. Of course, if you're not using SDK (including documents), it's all your freedom. But I cannot imagine development without SDK.

Comment: @Eonil: Yes, it can be used for development. Obviously not for production code, because you would need to be enrolled in the iPhone dev Program to get it on the App Store anyway. I was talking about for example hobbyist developing, a way to try your work on your own device without becoming a paid iPhone developer.

Comment: @Eonil Recent developments are that in fact jailbreaking is legal. http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/07/feds-ok-iphone-jailbreaking/ Still, one has to decide whether it is a good idea or not.

Comment: @Mk12 If you're talking about only 'using' (including programming) without any Apple supplied 'SDK's, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Yes.
They did their best.
They hacked the ROMs and .ipsws.
Like I said above, they tried to protect it.
And iPhone OS is protected by Apple, but the people try harder to hack the iPhone because it is more popular.